# Is it possible to debug Turtle scripts (equivalent of "-x" flag in bash)?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I've recently started using Haskell [Turtle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle) library to replace some of my shell scripts.

Is there a way to somehow enable echoing of built in Turtle commands (like cd) ala `set -x` in bash scripts? I find it quite problematic to debug Turtle scripts in cases where many commands are executed and one of them fails with exception (like `cp` command with `Exception:openBinaryFile: does not exist`). Alternatively do you have some recommendation how to quickly isolate problems like these, so that I don't have to intersperse `puStrLn/echo` commands throughout my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, it is not possible, as turtle does not provide tracing. For example, `mv` is defined only with Haskell function (no shell call), so there is no way to print anything when it is ran:

```
mv :: MonadIO io => FilePath -> FilePath -> io ()
mv oldPath newPath = liftIO (Filesystem.rename oldPath newPath)
```

---

This limitation mentioned in the documentation, where the author recommends to take a look at [Shelly](https://github.com/yesodweb/Shelly.hs#shelly), which is similar but provide extra features:

> turtle is designed to be beginner-friendly, but as a result lacks
>   certain features, like tracing commands. If you feel comfortable using
>   turtle then you should also check out the Shelly library which
>   provides similar functionality.